# How to open .jl file

Tags: julia

I want to open a `.jl` file and convert it to a readable file preferably in `.xls` format.
I do not have any any idea about Julia language.
Is there a file opener for `jl` files?

Answer (score 8):

I came here with the same question, but since the file I was looking at was clearly *JSON* data, I did some more searching.

The `.jl` file extension also refers to *JSON lines*, sometimes instead a `.jsonl` extension.

More here: http://jsonlines.org/

You can search for `.json` to Excel to find a converter, e.g. https://json-csv.com/ (this worked fine on my JSON lines file).

Answer (score 2):

A `.jl` file is a julia script.
It is source code.
Not data.

You can open it up in any text editor, e.g. notepad on windows.
However, it won't normally contain anything useful to you unless you want to edit that code.
(It might contain some array literals that you want, I guess)

Perhaps you mean to ask "How can I open a `.jld` file"? 
Which is a julia HDF5 file. 
In which case please ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, Julia is a script language therefor the file can be opened in a text editor like Notepad++, Vim, etc. Do not use word processor (like LibreOffice Writer) if you want to modify it, but it's OK if you want to read only.

To get started:
https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/